# Why is the size of an NSMutableArray that contains three JSON objects returning 1 and not 3?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

Please help me understand this, but I have an NSMutableArray, where an `NSLog` contains the following contents:

```
(
        (
                {
            day = 0;
            "end_time" = "21:00";
        },
                {
            day = 0;
            "end_time" = "21:00";
        },
                {
            day = 0;
            "end_time" = "21:00";
        }
    )
)
```

When I perform `[array count]`, it returns me 1, and not 3. I see 3 objects within the array, so why does it think there's only 1 object?

Maybe I'm not understanding? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far I can see, you have an array with one array object in it, and this second array contains 3 objects, not the first one.

```
( <-- first array braces open

only one object and it is another array -- 
 -->(
                {
            day = 0;
            "end_time" = "21:00";
        },
                {
            day = 0;
            "end_time" = "21:00";
        },
                {
            day = 0;
            "end_time" = "21:00";
        }
    ) < -- this another array braces close
) <-- end of your first array
```

Answer (score 1):

The NSMutableArray has ONE array object within it and this array contains three objects.

To get the count to return 3 you must do:

```
   [[array objectAtIndex:0] count];
```

Answer (score 1):

Example:

`NSMutableArray *arrOuter;` // Your array with Objects

`NSMutableArray *arrInner;`

`arrInner = [arrOuter objectAtIndex:0];` or `[arrOuter firstObject];`

`int count = [arrInner count];` // You will get count 3 now